# How push object onto array of array in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

i want to create a object such as this

```
$scope.allBooks = {
                books:[
                         {
                          name:"",
                          id:""
                         } 
                          {
                          name:"",
                          id:""
                         }
                        // can be add another object
                       ]
                  books:[
                         {
                          name:"",
                          id:""
                         } 
                          {
                          name:"",
                          id:""
                         }
                       ]

             }
```

in fact be able to add more object to books and also add more books to allBooks. 
my solution is this

```
  $scope.allBooks = {};
  $scope.allBooks.books= [];
  var b= {
    name:"",
    id:""
  };
  $scope.allBooks.books.push(b);
```

my problem is how to add more object to books and also add more array to allBooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually instead of adding properties dynamically you should rethink the structure of the allBooks object you're trying to create. The way I understand it, is that you have a collection of books belonging together, which in their turn belong to another collection. In other words you have an array of arrays.

That would turn your object into something like the following:

```
$scope.allBooks =  [
     { id: 0,
       name: 'Harry Potter Collection',
       books: [{
                 id: 0,
                 name: 'Goblet of Fire',
                 ISBN-13: '1212245'
               },{},...] //here are the books that belong to this collection
     },
     { id: 1,
       name: 'Lord Of The Rings Collection',
       books: [{},...] //LOTR books
 ]
```

This will allow you to push a collection of books to your **allBooks** collection.

```
var newCollection = {
        id:2,
        name: 'AnotherCollection',
        books: []
};

var newBook = {
        id: 1354,
        name: 'Eloquent Javascript 2',
        ISBN-13: 978-1593272821
};

newCollection.books.push(newBook) //push a new book to this collection

$scope.allBooks.push(newCollection);
```

There are ofcourse more solutions to your problem but I'd go with a collection of collections.

Comment: thanks for your reply :) . how add new book to books in newCollection[0] or newCollection[1] and ...

Comment: I have made a small [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HlCuWpGwWhiKeWZe9Z62?p=preview) to get you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

Just do what you've done already:

```
$scope.allBooks.books2 = [];
$scope.allBooks.books2.push(b);
$scope.allBooks.books3 = [];
$scope.allBooks.books3.push(b);
```

Comment: "One or two or more" -> sounds like a good use case for an array. ;)